# Averaging grades math not displaying correctly

Tags: java, loops, average

Can not for the life of me figure out why my average is not displaying correctly I've looked at it for like 2 hours.

```
import java.util.Scanner;
public class midterm
{
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
       Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);
       int examScore =0;
       int averageExamScore = 0;
       int numStudent=0;
       int sum=0;

       while(examScore >= 0)
           {
            System.out.println("Enter exam scores (enter negative number to quit): ");
            examScore = keyboard.nextInt();
            numStudent++;
            sum = sum + examScore;
          }
       if(numStudent > 0)
           {
              averageExamScore = sum/numStudent;

           }
        else
           {
              System.out.println("No scores to average");
           }
    }
}
```

Comment: int/int will yeild an int and smallNumber/largeNumber will yield 0 as result, averageExamScore = (double)sum/numStudent

Comment: and you haven't output averageExamScore,

Comment: Wow, I'm way to tired to see that, yikes.

Answer (score 2):

The issue here is integer division.

```
averageExamScore = sum/numStudent;
```

All three of these arguments are integers, which means:

- If you cast a part of your quotient to `double`, you'd lose precision (and fail compilation)

  Example:

  ```
   averageExamScore = (double)sum/numStudent; // wouldn't compile
  ```
- The floor of the quotient `sum/numStudent` is provided instead of the whole number (so for a number like `4.9` you'd get `4`).

You can fix this in a few ways:

- Declare `averageExamScore` to be a `double`.  This is required.
- Either cast `sum` or `numStudent` to a `double`, or change their type to `double`.

Comment: Thanks a ton man, I suppose its so late I'm forgetting the basics haha

Answer (score 1):

You have defined `averageExamScore` as an integer, so integer arithmetic will be applied.

e.g.

```
 5 / 2 == 2
 1 / 2 == 0
```

Make `averageExamScore` into a double, and also cast your other integers to doubles.

**Edit**

To print out

do

```
 if(numStudent > 0)
 {
   averageExamScore = sum/numStudent;
   System.out.println ("average score is " + averageExamScore );
 }
```

Comment: Assuming that there is more than one `numStudent`, it will never get into the else block

Comment: I thought maybe that was the problem, however it doesn't change anything.

Answer (score 0):

Go through the following code,

```
public class MidTerm {

 public static void main(String[] args) {
    Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);
    int examScore = 0;
    double averageExamScore = 0;
    int numStudent = 0;
    int sum = 0;

    while (true) {
        System.out.print("Enter exam scores (enter negative number to quit): ");
        examScore = keyboard.nextInt();
        if (examScore >= 0) {
            numStudent++;
            sum += examScore;
        } else break;
    }

    if (numStudent > 0) {
        averageExamScore = sum / numStudent;
        System.out.println("Avarage score is : " + averageExamScore);
    } else System.out.println("No scores to average");
 }
```

}

- averageExamScore variable should be a double otherwise it can not stored floating point values

Good Luck !!!